# Sort data by date and then by values

Tags: sql

I am having a problem with SQL expression. Let's have a table:

| Created Date | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/5/24 | True |
| 2022/5/24 | False |
| 2022/5/24 | Not Close Yet |
| 2022/5/26 | True |
| 2022/5/26 | True |
| 2022/5/28 | False |

I am trying to get output such as this:

| Created Date | Result Type | Count of Results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/5/24 | True | 1 |
| 2022/5/24 | False | 1 |
| 2022/5/24 | Not Close Yet | 1 |
| 2022/5/26 | True | 2 |
| 2022/5/28 | False | 1 |

I know there has to be some simple way of transforming, but my summary tries were failure.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of database you have, but this uses SQL Server syntax to wrap the identifier names that would otherwise cause an issue. Other databases have a slightly different syntax here.

```
SELECT [Created Date], Result As [Result Type], count(*) As [Count of results]
FROM [MyTable] 
GROUP BY [Created Date], Result
```

Comment: SQL in deed.... Is it that simple? Jeees, thank you very much, looks great...

Comment: And ISO/ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"Created Date"`. I even think SQL Server supports that too, or?